# Bing Maps. Change scalebar from Imperial to Metric?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, bing-maps

As title says... been looking on [Bing Maps API](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/ajax/) and can´t find anything about how to change scalebar from Imperial to Metric... any suggestions anyone?
AJAX v6.3

To make the question a little bit more clear... Im asking for if there is some kind of solution programmaticly to show the scalebar in metric?
Or if there is just a method to show only the metric scalebar.

What I´ve read, the bing map read your local settings in the browser to see if you are in a country that uses Imperial or Metric system.

And I´ve goggle:d it too... :P

Comment: tried [google](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp7-wpfeatures/metric-system/2c041fff-955b-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5)?

Comment: it's something like bing, it allows you to find hints like in the page hidden under google above (the imperial/metric system is used in bing maps depending on browser locale settings) ;)

Comment: That still didn´t answer my question. And even if I change locale settings in my browser to Swedish and sitting in Sweden, it still shows everything in miles. And yes, my windows 7 is in Swedish too.

Answer (score 0):

To change the scale bar unit, you can do this through the specific method VEMap.SetScaleBarDistanceUnit(), see the MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412528.aspx

Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.3"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
         var map = null;
         var clickEvent = null;

         function GetMap()
         {  
            map = new VEMap('myMap');            
            map.LoadMap();
            map.SetScaleBarDistanceUnit(VEDistanceUnit.Kilometers);    // Could also be VEDistanceUnit.Miles
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="GetMap();" style="font-family: Arial">
      <div id='myMap' style="position: relative; width: 800px; height: 400px;">
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```